# How to attach a rigid body to a cloth simulator

Tags: modifiers, physics, rigid-body-simulation, cloth-simulation

I'm trying to make a parachute that can hold rigid body items as they fall and slow the rigid body's fall. I've tried using wind to make the parachute fall slower, but I can't figure out how exactly to attach the rigid body object to the parachute. How would I do this? I've tried using hooks from the parachute ropes to the rigid body, but this only stretches the parachute.

Comment: I think rigid bodies can only be controlled with rigid body constraints. I've never been able to get them to work like I want, though.

Answer (score 3):

This may not be the approach you're looking for.  I've posted it in case you can use it.  The Blend file is below...

[image]

The canopy and ropes are mesh and joined as one object.  The lower end of the ropes are all apexed as one and those vertices given a hook.

The box and cylinder are separate objects.  Both are given rigid body physics which is delayed until the box reaches the ground at frame 70.  (Animated at frame 1 and switched to "Dynamic" at frame 70)

A Nav(igation)-Empty (the large circle at the canopy) is the parent of all four - the hook, canopy, box, and cylinder.  The Nav-Empty is keyframed to descend and sway and all 4 objects are forced to follow.

At frame 70 when the box reaches the ground, it's physics are switched to "Dynamic".  So too is the cylinder's.

The physics engine takes over and they ignore their parentage and react with the ground which is also a rigid body, but "Passive" and set to "Mesh".

Both the box and cylinder's antics are then baked from frame 1 to when they settle down at frame 93.
(all boxes are ticked in the baking panel)
Once baked, make sure each object's physics are switched off and the redundant physics strips in the Dopesheet, deleted.

With the canopy, box, and cylinder under no constraints, (operating purely under keyframes), the parentage of the canopy's apex hook can then be changed to be a child of the box from frame 1.
When it's played again, nothing should change.  The canopy's ropes however will follow it's parent about on the ground, and being a hook, won't pull the canopy about with it.

All that's left is to rotate the canopy's Nav-Empty a little as the box shoots off to the left, then morph the canopy's deflating shape with shapekeys as it 'floats' to the ground.

[image]