# Parachute animation

Tags: physics

I'm trying to use cloth physics with this parachute animation but I tried all the variables and I cannot simulate something that could look real.

- [Blender file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/67o46atwb4ft1cc/app2.blend?dl=0)
- [Viewport animation](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lx5myba57pflans/0001-0200.mp4?dl=0)

Comment: looks nice!!! what do you expect?

Comment: Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: I ask the same question as @Chris.  Yours looks a lot better than mine. (here) - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183341/how-to-attach-a-rigid-body-to-a-cloth-simulator/183477#183477